# SQL ORACLE, Differences

Tags: sql, oracle, difference, arithmetic-expressions

Here is the code

```
 select sum(post_sales) from post_sales;
```

Gives 50,000

```
select sum(sales) from sales;
```

Gives 100,000

**I want to subtract 100,000 - 50,000**

What is the syntax for this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put these in a `select`:

```
select ( (select sum(sales) from sales) -
         (select sum(post_sales) from post_sales)
       ) as diff
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
WITH SS AS (SELECT SUM(SALES) AS TOTAL_SALES FROM SALES),
     SPS AS (SELECT SUM(POST_SALES) AS TOTAL_POST_SALES FROM POST_SALES)
SELECT TOTAL_SALES, TOTAL_POST_SALES, TOTAL_SALES - TOTAL_POST_SALES AS SALES_DIFF
  FROM SS
  CROSS JOIN SPS
```

Here we use Common Table Expressions `SS` and `SPS` to compute total sales and total post sales. We then cross join these CTE's, which are guaranteed to return a single row each and thus the cross join is guaranteed to return a single row, compute the difference, and we're done.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9bbaddf7b1e39c4ff77e0c3fb9b7f2c)

Best of luck.